# How to correctly use collection in strict mode with async await

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I'm trying to figure out how to use the collection `strict` mode with async/await. It needs a callback, but I can't figure out how to use it properly since it doesn't seem to be running any command.

It gives the error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
```

Here's what I have so far.

```
    const cursor = 
        await
        db
            .collection(
                "invalidator",
                {
                    strict: true
                },
                async function (error, cursor) 
                {
                    console.log(chalk.yellow("running callback"))
                    const result = await
                    cursor
                        .insertOne({
                            // created: new Date(),
                            test: "test"
                        })

                    console.log(result)
                }
            )
```

`db` is just the MongoClient

```
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(
        url,
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
        },
    )
```

Comment: async makes a function return a promise.  I think you only need a callback here.  Why do you think you need async here?

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Db.html#collection `.collection()` does not return a Promise. If you're expecting to 'await` the completion of the inner `callback` then you need to wrap the whole thing in a `Promise` "manually". i.e `await new Promise((resolve,reject) => db.collection('name', (err, collection) => /* do stuff */ resolve()))`

Comment: @NeilLunn I tried it without the async, but I'm just not sure how to get the collection instance back. I tried a `return collection` in the callback, but it gives me a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertOne' of undefined`.

Comment: @JimB. I'm just trying to get the instance back in order to continue the queries, since it gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertOne' of undefined`

Comment: You're not checking the error.  Is there an error?

Comment: @JimB. There's no error (surprisingly because the collection name was incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear the [`collection()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Db.html#collection) method does not return a `Promise`. It's not actually meant to return anything and the `callback` interface is only needed for "strict mode" which means MongoDB cannot "create a collection" which does not already exist by the given name when you subsequently try to do anything.

In the shortest demonstrator, you basically need to wrap the "whole thing" in a `Promise` manually if you intend to `await` the actions inside the `callback`:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, opts);

    let db = client.db('test');

    // Expect to wait or fail if the collection named does not already exist
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.collection('test', { strict: true }, async (err, collection) => {
        if (err) reject(err);

        // really should have an "inner" try..catch to "bubble" any errors.
        try {
          // insert something
          let result = await collection.insertOne({ a: 1 });
          log(result);
          resolve();               // resolve the Promise
        } catch(e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    })
    log("I waited");

    client.close();

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }
})()
```

For completeness, you really should have a `try..catch` around any "inner" operations of the callback such as the [`insertOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#insertOne) here and subsequently `reject()` on any error within the `catch` block.

Comment: So the main reason for me using `{strict: true}` is to ensure that I am not inserting into a non-existent collection (in case of spelling errors). I can use async/await fine when I don't include `{ strict: true }`

Comment: @A.Lau Actually just checked that. I "presumed" the `strict` was **implied** by the `callback`, but it actually is not. Listing corrected/tested and working as expected.

Comment: seems like a pretty clumsy way to get the original effect but with `{strict: true}` included. but I guess at least it works

Comment: @A.Lau Well you could always simply wrap getting the collection reference in a promise i.e `let collection = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => db.collection('test',{ strict: true }, (err,collection) => { if (err) reject(err); resolve(collection) })` if that suits your sensibilities better, but the basic point is the driver method does not return a `Promise` natively and like everywhere else  that is a similar case, you do the wrapping manually yourself. Or "promisify" by some other external library if you already have such a thing loaded as a dependency.